# Chrome 1px gap between images when resizing

Tags: html, css

i have like an image collage that i made like this:

```
.artikli{
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 0px;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 0px;
    max-width: 800px;
    line-height: 0;
 }

.artikli a{
    display: inline-block; 
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    }
```

but when i resize 1px gap starts to show on some window sizes and its only on chrome, here is an screenshot :

[image: http://pokit.org/get/?a8fabbbab29e26f1825d90ab7db35b94.jpg]

when I delete from `.artikli a` the `position:relative;` the gap disappears but then the hover doesn't work. Any ideas ?

This is the hover effect:

```
.hovv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #c90055 url(../img/plus.png) no-repeat center center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-out 1s;
    -moz-transition: all ease-out 1s;
    -o-transition: all ease-out 1s;
     transition: all ease-out 1s; 
}

.artikli a:hover > .hovv {
     opacity: 0.7;
 }
```

and this is the html structure

```
<a href="imagepath/2014/04/172.jpg" rel="shadowbox[1]"><img width="399" height="600" src="imagepath/2014/04/172.jpg" class="attachment-single-article" alt="17"><span class="hovv"></span></a>
```

Thanks !

EDIT:

so i forgot to write that the html goes like this (used foundation framework so everything is responsive and here is now 3 images just like an example but there will be a lot more of them):

```
<div class="small-8 columns artikli">

 <a href="imagepath/2014/04/172.jpg" rel="shadowbox[1]"><img width="399" height="600" src="imagepath/2014/04/172.jpg" class="attachment-single-article" alt="17"><span class="hovv"></span></a>

 <a href="imagepath/2014/04/172.jpg" rel="shadowbox[1]"><img width="399" height="600" src="imagepath/2014/04/172.jpg" class="attachment-single-article" alt="17"><span class="hovv"></span></a>

 <a href="imagepath/2014/04/172.jpg" rel="shadowbox[1]"><img width="399" height="600" src="imagepath/2014/04/172.jpg" class="attachment-single-article" alt="17"><span class="hovv"></span></a>

</div>
```

EDIT2:

this is the issue just the hover doesn't work but you can resize the window.
**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5w6N6/)**

Comment: is it possible provide a fiddle or live demo...?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5w6N6/ here is a fiddle, just resize the browser and you will see the 1px gap appears, only the hover here dosen't work, not sure why...

Answer (score 0):

ok i am atttempting to answer a question whic i find is not complete. u have mentioned classes .artikli . but your code especially the html part does not show any part of those classes. Now all I did was to add a a:hover part to your css like ...

```
a:hover {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #c90055 url(../img/plus.png) no-repeat center center;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: all ease-out 1s;
-moz-transition: all ease-out 1s;
-o-transition: all ease-out 1s;
 transition: all ease-out 1s; 
}
```

instead of .hovv part of your css. the fiddle can be found in http://jsfiddle.net/y4TjN/ . hopefully this helps. but remember i had very little to work with here

Comment: sorry i forgot to add a div that contains all of the images i will update